# Valet with mysql? How to insert and use database?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I successfully started `mysql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mysql). But i dont know how to access that mysql. How to insert database . I tried with 127.0.0.1 but i get this message.

> Access forbidden!

Answer (score 0):

According to Valet documentation, you should be able to connect to mysql, using `root` as user and an empty string as password. 
I'm using Sequel Pro as administrator with success.